# Database design for users with multiple balances

Tags: mysql

I have the following situation: (MYSQL)
Each user that registers for a game will have the ability to have balances for up to 100 different currencies. I was originally going to do just a user table with ~105 columns for each user (userid, name, email, pw, currency1, currency2, ... ,currency100)  but it seemed silly. There is the other route of just placing each individual balance with a currency id and user id in one massive balance table, but that seems a bit silly if I were to scale up. What is the best way to store 100 data points on a user keeping in mind efficiency and scalability

Comment: Before we even get to the answer, may we ask what is the use case for which a single user would have balances in 100 different currencies?  Would these correspond to actual accounts of some kind?  I would go with the "massive" balance approach.

Comment: I guess to simplify away from currencies we can use items database for a game. Suppose you have 100 possible items each user can have, would you go with a item table, and in that item table each item along with a user id and quantity. So when pulling data, a query such as 'select * from items where userid=231' and the loop through and get all the items?

Comment: I would only do this if I were 100% certain that another item column would never needed to be added.  If so, then I would really treat items as sort of immutable properties of each user, such as an address or username.  If not, then I would go with the other approach.

Comment: I would go with 3 tables, users (user info), items (item info) and users_items which contains user_id, item_id and quantity. Starting with a normalised db will make life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kind of problem that relational databases like MySQL were made for. It's a classic "one-to-many" relationship of each user owning many currencies. So technically, it's not silly to put the currencies in a separate table.

On the other hand, this is actually a "many-to-many" relationship, because many currencies can have many owners. In this case, you need a third table, AKA a "junction table", that's equivalent to user bank accounts.

The most efficient way to set up the tables is with ID numbers for the primary keys of each table. Numerical IDs are easier and faster for the server to process when retrieving data.

The primary key of the junction table could actually be a "composite key" using both of the primary keys from two other tables. However, it may be better to make unique bank account IDs in this case, because you want many currency IDs available in each bank trading account.

Designing a database is challenging, so it might help to draw visual diagrams of all your different data catagories and how they relate to each other. Users will probably expect access to balance histories and bank statements in a game as well as real life. And currencies should change value depending on supply and demand, and be interchangeable depending on rates of exchange.

[Source](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html)